# How do I make a function split an interval into "n" subintervals?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function called `partition_pts(a,b,n)` that will take a range of numbers on the interval `a` to `b` with `n` subintervals.

So far my code is

```
def partition_pts(a,b,n):
    lst = [x / n for x in range(a*n, b*n, n+1)]
    return lst
```

But this doesn't return the correct values.The correct answer should be `partition_pts(-1, 2, 6)` would return `[-1.0 , -0.5 , 0.0 , 0.5 , 1.0 , 1.5 , 2.0]`

Comment: What have you done to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to `range` is step, not the total number of items. This should work:

```
lst = [a + x * (b - a) / n for x in range(n + 1)]
```